# Gambler's ruin with partial gains

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution, markov-chain-montecarlo, bernoulli-distribution

Consider a gambler going into a casino with K dollars to play games with the standard conditions (independent trials, Bernoulli process with success probability p). In case of a loss they lose 1 dollar. In case of a win, they win a token. After having R tokens, they earn an extra dollar. What is the probability that they have become bankrupt after playing X games? We should consider that a player that has 0 dollars is effectively bankrupt, no matter how many tokens they still have.

So far, I have managed to model it using a Markov Chain and Monte Carlo simulations, but I'm interested in figuring out if there is a closed form solution.

For the case R=0 it becomes a classical problem (losing 1 dollar after a lost game, keeping their money in case of a win, no token accumulation) and the probability can be modelled as a truncated binomial distribution as

\begin{equation}
 Pr(x) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0 & \text{if $x < k$} \\
  {x-1\choose k-1}  (1-p)^kp^{x-k} & \text{if $x \geq k$} \\
 \end{array}
 \right. 
\end{equation}

However, when adding the R tokens needed to earn a full dollar, multiple truncated binomials start to appear at periodic intervals with period R+1 (see image for K=5, R=3), and becoming bankrupt at certain intervals becomes impossible. Is there a way to model this in a compact way as the simple case with R = 0?

[image]

Comment: Unless I don't understand something, this can't be right; why would there be 0 probability to lose $K=5$ dollars after 9 games? Increasing $R$ should only increase probability of going bankrupt since it delays receipt of money.

Comment: @bdeonovic - Sorry, there was a mistake in the labelling of the X axis. However, the case still applies. For instance, think about going bankrupt after 8 games. There is no combination of hits and misses that leaves him with exactly 0 dollars at round 8 e.g. losing 5 games and winning 3 leaves him at 1$; losing 6 games and winning 2 means hi will go bankrupt before game 8. So, it makes sense that for some trials the probability will be 0. Then, the varying probabilities that follow periodically are due to different amount of combinations leading to bankruptcy.

Comment: Wouldn't modeling them as winning $1/R$ dollars whenever they win do the trick?  If $R=3$, and they win 2 times in a row then lose, they go bankrupt, just as if they had zero dollars instead of 2/3 of a dollar.  Whenever they lose, they retain the fractional dollars, e.g., go from 1 1/3 dollars to 1/3 dollar, just like retaining a token.

Comment: @jbowman - Definitely, one could do that. However, it is not clear to me that modeling that would end up in a distribution that could be easily expressed in a compact analytical form. Regardless of the configuration, I would be interested in being able to express the distribution analytically.

Comment: This paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.4203.pdf ( Gambler’s ruin probability - a general formula by Guy Katriel) may provide you with what you need...

Comment: Thanks, @jbowman for the reference. This seems to reaffirm my notion that manually computing all the solutions is unfeasible. In doing the computations manually I did see a pattern emerge. Consider the case for k=3  and r=2:

$P(1) = 0$; $P(2) = 0$ - From now on, a combination of wins and losses lead to ruin:
$P(3) = p^3$; $P(4) = C_4 (1-p)p^3$; $P(5) = 0$ (no combinations); $P(6) = C_6 (1-p)^2 p^4$; $P(7) = C_7 (1-p)^3 p^4$; $P(8) = 0$; $P(9) = C_9 (1-p)^4 p^5$; $P(10) = C_{10} (1-p)^5 p^5$; $P(11) = 0$ - Finding $C(x)$ would generalize this, but this might have to be done numerically...?

Comment: I believe you're right; there is a recursion for $C$, I believe, but of course "recursion" means "numerically, not analytic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Formulating the Markov chain:** Although you didn't explicitly specify it, I will assume that the gambler instantly cashes in their tokens for a dollar as soon as they have $R$ tokens (i.e., they don't save their tokens when they could cash them in).  Under this assumption the state space for the model can be described by a single integer state variable:

$$s = R x_\text{Dollars} + x_\text{Tokens},$$

where $x_\text{Dollars} = \lfloor s/R \rfloor$ is the number of dollars they have and $x_\text{Tokens} = s - R \times \lfloor s/R \rfloor$ is the number of tokens they have.  For all allowable states with $s_t \geqslant R$ the transition probabilities for the Markov chain are:

$$p(s_{t+1} | s_t) = 
\begin{cases}
1-p & & & \text{for } s_{t+1}=s_t-R, \\[6pt]
p & & & \text{for } s_{t+1}=s_t+1, \\[8pt]
0 & & & \text{otherwise}, \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

and every state with $0 \leqslant s_t < R$ is an absorbing state that constitutes ruin.  (The gambler may still have some tokens left, but not enough to trade in for a dollar.)

---

**Expressing the Markov chain in matrix form:** To facilitate analysis, let $\mathbf{I}_*$ and $\mathbf{I}_{**}$ be $R \times R$ matrices with elements given as follows:

$$\mathbf{I}_{*} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\mathbf{I}_{**} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

(Observe that when we put together $[\mathbf{I}_{*}, \mathbf{I}_{**}]$ we get a block that contains an identity matrix that has been shifted to the right by one unit.)  The [transition probability matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) for the Markov chain can be written up to any desired dimension (depending on the upper bound of the number of games you want to use) in block form (where all the blocks are $R \times R$ matrices) as:

$$\mathbf{P} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \cdots \\
(1-p)\mathbf{I} & p\mathbf{I}_{*} & p\mathbf{I}_{**} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \cdots \\
\mathbf{0} & (1-p)\mathbf{I} & p\mathbf{I}_{*} & p\mathbf{I}_{**} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \cdots \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & (1-p)\mathbf{I} & p\mathbf{I}_{*} & p\mathbf{I}_{**} & \mathbf{0} & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

(We label the states corresponding to the rows and columns by $s=0,1,2,3,...$ so the first row/column is labelled as zero.)  Now, if you take some upper bound $T$ on the number of games you are looking at, you can then determine that the maximum possible state $\bar{s} = RK + T$, which allow you to form a finite transition probability matrix $\mathbf{P}_T$ up to that maximum state.  You can then take the appropriate powers of the transition probability matrix to get the marginal distributions of the state variable after each game.  It is then simple to find the probability of ruin after $t$ games by summing all the transition probabilities from the starting state to the ruin states:

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{Ruin after } t \text{ games}| s_0 = K)
= \sum_{s=0}^{R-1} [\mathbf{P}_T^t]_{KR, s}.$$

Comment: Thanks, @ben! This is exactly the route that I took and I had managed to formulate the probability transition matrix (also by applying a high enough upper bound). I was hoping to find a solution in the same form as the simpler case with r=0, but so far both your answer as well as the paper linked above seem to suggest that a Markov Chain is the right way to model this process. What do you think?